# Need to any help for solving an infinite integral

Tags: calculus, integration

I need to help the following integral

$$\int\dfrac{dx}{\sqrt[n - 1]{x^{2n - 4}} \sqrt[2n - 2]{(1 - x^2)^{n + 1}}}$$
where $n\in \mathbb{N}$ and $n \ge 3$.

**My answer**

Using the change of variable $x = sin (\alpha)$, we obtain

$$\int \frac{d \alpha}{\sin^{\frac{2n -4}{n -1}}(\alpha) \cos^{\frac{2}{n - 1}}(\alpha)}.$$

Now we use the change of variable $z = \tan (\alpha)$ and we get

$$\int z^{\frac{4 - 2n}{n -1}} dz = \frac{n - 1}{3 - n} z^{\frac{3 - n}{n -1}} + constant. $$
Finally we get
$$\frac{n - 1}{3 - n}\frac{\sqrt[n - 1]{x^{3 - n}}}{\sqrt[2n - 2]{(1 - x^2)^{
3 - n}}} + constant.$$
Could someone help for solving this integral?

Thanks for any help

Comment: See [incomplete beta function](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/IncompleteBetaFunction.html)

Comment: what are your efforts?

Comment: It can be ecpressed as agayss hypergeometric series $2F1 (a, b;c;x).. $

Comment: May be it can be expressed by any other special function.

Comment: @Tyma Gaidash  Is thefollowing answer wrong?

Comment: @ Z Ahmad Is the following answer wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the change of variable $x = sin (\alpha)$, we obtain

$$\int \frac{d \alpha}{\sin^{\frac{2n -4}{n -1}}(\alpha) \cos^{\frac{2}{n - 1}}(\alpha)}.$$

Now we use the change of variable $z = \tan (\alpha)$ and we get

$$\int z^{\frac{4 - 2n}{n -1}} dz = \frac{n - 1}{3 - n} z^{\frac{3 - n}{n -1}} + constant. $$
Finally we get
$$\frac{n - 1}{3 - n}\frac{\sqrt[n - 1]{x^{3 - n}}}{\sqrt[2n - 2]{(1 - x^2)^{
3 - n}}} + constant.$$

Comment: This appears to be correct!

Answer (score -1):

In general the integral can be written in the following form $\int \frac{dx}{x^3(\frac{1}{x^2}-1)^{\frac{n+1}{2n-2}}}$. Further you have to write $\frac{dx}{x^3}=-\frac{1}{2}d\frac{1}{x^2}$.

$\sqrt[n-1]{x^{2n-4}}=x^{\frac{2n-4}{n-1}}$

$\sqrt[2n-2]{(1-x^2)^{n+1}}=x^{2.\frac{n+1}{2n-2}}.(1/x^2-1)^{\frac{n+1}{2n-2}}$

$x^{\frac{2n-4}{n-1}}.x^{2.\frac{n+1}{2n-2}}=x^3$